# python create list of nested dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to get XML data and put it into an array of dicts. However, it doesnt work as expected. The same dict just gets added to the list. How can I make the correct dict get added to the list, at the correct stages of the nested for loop?

The printed listy should look like the following:

```
[OrderedDict([('name', ‘dogs’), ('type', ‘housed’), ('value', ‘123’)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', ‘cats’), ('type', ‘wild’), ('value', ‘456’)]),
 OrderedDict([('name', ‘mice’), ('type', ‘housed’), ('value', ‘789’)])]
```

Is it better to put it in a dict instead of a list?

```
Here is the XML:
<window>
    <window class="Obj" name="ray" type="housed">
        <animal name="dogs",  value = "123" />
        <species name="sdogs",  value = "s123" />
    </window>
    <window class="Obj" name="james" type="wild">
        <animal name="cats", type="wild", value = "456" />
        <species name="scats", type="swild", value = "s456" />
    </window>
    <window class="Obj" name="bob" type="housed">
        <animal name="mice",  value = "789" />
        <species name="smice",  value = "s789" />
    </window>
</window>
```

And heres the code (sorry if there are a few mistakes, I can correct them as this is an example of a larger code):

```
import sys
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from collections import OrderedDict

soup = bs(open("test.xml"),"lxml")
dicty = OrderedDict()
listy = [];
Objs=soup.findAll('window',{"class":"Obj"})

#print Objs
for Obj in Objs:
    Objarr =  OrderedDict()     #### move this down
    #I want to add data to the array here:
    #print Obj
    for child in Obj.children:
        Objarr.update({"namesss" : Obj['name']})
        if child.name is not None:
            if child.name == "species":
                print Obj['name']
                print child['value']
                #Also, adding data to the array here:
                Objarr.update({"name" : Obj['name']})
                Objarr.update({"type" : Obj['type']})
                Objarr.update({"value": child['name']})
    listy.append(Objarr)        #### dedent this

pprint.pprint(listy)
```

Comment: Please add some example of `Objs` content as well as the expected `listy`.

Comment: yes doing so now :)

Comment: hist ettanany ive added the list object returned.

Comment: You need also to add some example of `Objs` content.

Comment: touche, I saw that request, just doing that now

Comment: ok, xml all added

Comment: Noticed a typo in the line `Objarr.update({"type" : " matrix”})` should be `Objarr.update({"type" : "matrix"})` is that in your code also or just in the question? If it's in your code it should throw a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Is your xml correct?

Comment: I dont think it is correct. Thanks so much everyone and sorry if I got some errors in my post. I will update it because I think im on the right track now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating a dictionary and appending it to the list. The result is that you keep using the same dictionary again and again. You should create a new dictionary before the beginning of the children loop and add after the loop, not inside.

I guess something like this:

```
import sys
import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from collections import OrderedDict

soup = bs(open("my.xml"),"lxml")
dicty = OrderedDict()
listy = [];
Objs=soup.findAll('window',{"class":"Obj"})
#print Objs
for Obj in Objs:
    Objarr =  OrderedDict()        #### move this down ####
    #I want to add data to the array here:
    for child in Obj.children:
        if child.name is not None:
            if child.name == "variable":
               #Also, adding data to the array here:
                Objarr.update({"name" : Obj['text']})
                Objarr.update({"type" : " matrix”})
                Objarr.update({"value": child['name']})
    listy.append(Objarr)           #### dedent this ####

pprint.pprint(listy)
```

Comment: No, I don't have enough input to test it (that's why I wrote `I guess`). But the `listy.append` in the original post doesn't seem correct, because it keeps adding the same OrderedDict and creates a list with many instances of the same object. My example shows how to (1) create a new OrderedDict, (2) add stuff into it and (3) add it to the list.

Comment: There are errors in your answer copied from the OP.

Comment: @Nurzhan very likely there are errors, but the two corrections highlighted by my comments address the question: the same changes applied to the real code (the code in the question is neither complete nor working) will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks so much, this was the correct answer. I've updated my code because it had huge errors, sorry about this. Still stenci managed to identify the problem tho. Thanks  :)

Comment: I'm glad it works :) An little advice about StackOverflow: you should not modify the question, otherwise the answers make no sense for future readers. You can add a section with further explanations related to comments or answers instead.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following to understand what your `objs` contains:

```
>>> soup = bs(open("my_xml.xml"),"lxml")
>>>
>>> objs = soup.findAll('window',{"class":"Obj"})
>>>
>>> for obj in objs:
...     for child in obj.children:
...         print child
...


<animal name="dogs" type="housed" value="123"></animal>


<animal name="cats" type="wild" value="456"></animal>


<animal name="mice" type="housed" value="789"></animal>


<window>
</window>
```

Means that the first element in `objs` is a `\n` and the last element is `<window>\n</window>` and between each other elements there a `\n` that separates each two elements.

To solve this issue, you need to convert you `listiterator` (`obj.children`) to a normal `list` like this `list(obj.children)` and then use these values for your list slicing: `start: 1, end: -2, step: 2`, like this `list(obj.children)[1:-2:2]`

This is the output in this case:

```
>>> for obj in objs:
...     for child in list(obj.children)[1:-2:2]:
...         print child
...
<animal name="dogs" type="housed" value="123"></animal>
<animal name="cats" type="wild" value="456"></animal>
<animal name="mice" type="housed" value="789"></animal>
```

Comment: Thanks I didnt realise you could use lists in this way.